# Writing conditional statements in XAML code

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, conditional-statements

I have this listBox that gets populated, each item can be either male or female depending on the 'SEX' property that is binded to the listBox. (Could be either 'M' for male and 'F' for female)...

For each item i would like to display either a male or female symbol based on the list items SEX property.

for instance if "{Binding SEX}" equals 'M':

```
<Image Source="../Images/male48.png" Visibility="Visible" />
```

and if "{Binding SEX}" equals 'F':

```
<Image Source="../Images/female48.png" Visibility="Visible" />
```

How exactly would I go about getting this to work?

Comment: Can't you bind the image Source property and have the complexity in your view model?

Answer (score 17):

A common approach to this problem is to create a value converter, this converts the value returned by a binding into some other value that relates to the property of a UI control.

You can create a converter that takes the sex and maps it to an image source:

```cs
public class SexToSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, string typeName, object parameter, string language)
  {
     string url = ((string)value == "M") ? "../Images/male48.png" :  "../Images/female48.png";
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(url , UriKind.Relative));
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, string typeName, object parameter, string language)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Using it in your XAML as follows:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Sex, Converter={StaticResource SexToSourceConverter }" />
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you very much! Just one question though. Where I use it in my XAML, is there an extra squigly brace missing at the end? e.g. ...SexToSourceConverter }}"

Comment: Also I'm getting this error stating: Error 1 'Pathportal.SexToSourceConverter' does not implement interface member 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)'... Any ideas?

Comment: When using MVVM we never bothered with ValueConverters, you've already got the ability to convert the value in the VM so why bother with the extra class? Wou'll eventually end up with dozens of converters or overly complex converters that try to do too much so they can be re-used in slightly different contexts

Comment: @BenCr 1. You are assuming that the OP is using MVVM. 2. The VM should know which images the view uses for which states, that would break the encapsulation of the view.

Comment: @ColinE 1. In the ConvertBack method, you could return Binding.DoNothing instead. 2. Don't you think you should let the OP have a go at learning how to write a converter himself?

Comment: 1. I'm not assuming, just commenting but he is binding to some sort of object somewhere 2. Does the converter not break the encapsulation of the view in the same way?  Who cares if it does break encapsulation if it makes things simpler?

Answer (score 4):

If someone is interested in how this could work, I've made a solution based on **ColinE**'s answer. First, you've to create a new class which contain the conditions you'll like to add to the XAML code:

```cs
public class MyNiceConverterName : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        // Your conditions here!
        return value_you_want_to_return; // E.g., a string, an integer and so on
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // Leave this like here, don't worry
    }
}
```

Call the class whatever you want (right now it's called `MyNiceConverterName`) and implement the `Convert()` method with the conditions you'd like to add to the XAML file. Remember to cast the `object value` to the type you're using (e.g., `(int)value` if it's an integer).

This is almost done! But not yet, first declare the converter in your XAML as a resource. You can paste this code below the namespaces declaration:

```
<Control.Resources>
    <converter:MyNiceConverterName xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:My_Namespace" x:Key="MyNiceConverterName" />
</Control.Resources>
```

You've to declare the namespace where you defined the class (i.e., remove `My_Namespace` with yours') and also rename `MyNiceConverterName` to your class name. The key will be the name defined to reference the converter within the XAML document, here I've used the same class name but you can freely change it.

Finally, it's time to use the converter. Put this and you're done:

```
{Binding variable_with_value, Converter={StaticResource MyNiceConverterName}}
```

Remember to change `variable_with_value` with the one you'd like to use within your binding.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, you saved me lots of time.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) or use two [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx).

For Siverlight [this is the correct IValueConverter link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), I am not sure if triggers are supported.

Comment: AFAIK triggers are not supported in Silverlight for WP7. The binding converter / IValueConverter advice is good though.

Comment: I believe triggers work in wp7, isn't that how Caliburn Micro actions work, I could be wrong though.